# How to reduce the size of image with cursor url?

Tags: html, css

I have an image with size 105x105. I am using it as cursor using this CSS script:

```
.class_1 .child_1 {
    cursor: url(theBell.png) 20 20, auto;
}
```

The image appears when I move the mouse over element, but it is too large.

I do not know how to reduce size of cursor.

I had some searching but found no positive results.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't reduce the size of the cursor. You need to reduce the size of the image. 36 * 36 px is the recommended size.

Some more useful information here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor#syntax

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Place the icon on the top left corner of the bounding box as it will be the interaction point of the cursor.
Well, I myself dug for the same but found nothing. However,

There is a trick that I crafted in order to achieve the same, i.e.,  **creating a bounding box around the icon and rendering them together**. Also, then output the file as 128x128 .ico to use it. The gap between the bounding box and the icon can be tweaked to one's liking.