# change custom cursor width height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cursor

My custom cursor for my website is only `80x112` pixels, yet when I set the custom cursor on the `body`,

```
cursor:url("/data/img/assets/UI/cursor.png"), auto;
```

It looks massive:

[image]

When it should retain the same dimensions as the png (80x112):

[image]

[The docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) do not show any way to alter the width/height. How can I accomplish this?

---

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ok934dg2/1/

Comment: @CertainPerformance not sure the URL / image matter, do they? The question is asking specifically about setting width/height on the cursor.

Comment: Well, better to provide one than to hope that someone who sees your question is willing to do some image searching themselves to find an image that might (or might not) reproduce the problem. Yep, thanks for the fiddle link!

Comment: @CertainPerformance I guess if you need it, I've added a fiddle above

Comment: Thanks. I think the cursor *is* retaining the same dimensions as intended (80x112), but that said size just looks too big, visually: https://jsfiddle.net/ok934dg2/2/ I don't think it's possible to change it with CSS, unfortunately: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33715491/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-image-with-cursor-url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351916/increase-cursor-size-in-html-body Might have to resize the cursor image itself

Comment: @CertainPerformance good to know, thank you! the pixel sizing in Photoshop is throwing me off. At 100% view, same dimensions, it looks much smaller